# T-SQL Job fail with Incorrect syntax near ' '. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 102)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Just wondering if some can help me figure out why this T-SQL script doesn't work. My experience in SQL is novice at best.

```sql
DELETE FROM ActiveUsers
WHERE HostName + CAST(HostId AS CHAR) IN (SELECT HostName + CAST(HostId AS CHAR)
     FROM ActiveUsers ACTUSR
     WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL)
     FROM master.dbo.sysprocesses SYSPRC
     WHERE SYSPRC.HostName = ACTUSR.HostName COLLATE database_default
     AND SYSPRC.HostProcess = ACTUSR.HostId
     GROUP BY SYSPRC.HostName, SYSPRC.HostProcess))
```

The error message is:

```
Executed as user: . Incorrect syntax near ' '. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 102)  Incorrect syntax near ' '. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 102).  The step failed.
```

Comment: I have updated my answer, please have a look.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have an extra closing bracket in the line
`WHERE NOT EXITS (SELECT NULL)`

**Update:**

*Ok, you have said that you removed the bracket after the select null in that case the following 2 points also apply*

- The `GROUP BY` clause in the subquery is redundant and can be safely removed since you have no aggregate function and you are just checking if results `NOT EXISTS`.
- Also one of the two sub queries can be removed which leaves you with the query below. This will delete records from `ActiveUsers` table where the `HostName` and `HostId` are not found in `the master.dbo.sysprocesses` table.

Try this, I have tested it and it worked fine for me.

```
DELETE FROM ActiveUsers
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL
FROM master.dbo.sysprocesses SYSPRC
WHERE SYSPRC.HostName = ActiveUsers.HostName COLLATE database_default
AND SYSPRC.HostProcess = ActiveUsers.HostId)
```

Comment: Thanks, Just tried with out it but still give the same error